# SOLR partial update inhibits document retrieve applying fq parameter

Tags: solr, solr4

I have a document indexed in Solr 4.5.1 with a list of several type of fields.
When I run a partial update by "ID" on a field the same document is no more searchable when applying `fq` param. It is searchable if I use the same filter in `q` param.

scenario example:

```
localhost:8983/corename/select?q=*:*&fq=fieldname:"DOC"
```

The document is returned.

After running partial update on "fieldname2...
The following query does not return the doc

```
localhost:8983/corename/select?q=*:*&fq=fieldname:"DOC"
```

The following query return the doc

```
localhost:8983/corename/select?q=*:*+fieldname:"DOC"
```

Any idea? Is it a Solr bug?

Answer (score 0):

The two queries you've shown are not identical - the latter is probably interpreted as `*:* OR fieldname:"DOC"`, depending on the value of `q.op` and the default operator in the schema. If it hasn't been configured, the default operator is `OR`.

My guess is that the field isn't stored, so after the atomic update, the field no longer has any value associated with it. To use the atomic update feature, all fields have to be marked as stored.

Comment: I'm sure the query is in AND and the fields are set as stored="true"

Comment: Add a minimal example that shows this happening (schema and example curl requests)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved...all searcheable fields have to be setted as stored="true". Otherwise they get lost during partial update.